# C# get exception message in catch (Exception) block

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have some code like this. I don't use exception object in my catch block, so resharper provide a hint to remove declaration of the exception object.

```
try
{
     //do some exception
}
catch (Exception)
{
     //I want to somehow see exception message here
}
```

But once if I want to explore the exception object under the debug, I don't see a opportunity to do it without code modifying, rebuilding solution, etc.

So, is any way to get exception object in this statement?

Comment: @Adil What the OP said is: "as I don't use **ex** in my code, ReSharper told me to delete the declaration, how can I see the exception details while debugging?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in the catch block. When code is stopped here, in Visual Studio select in the menu `Debug -> Windows -> Locals` to show local variables. There you will see `$exception` variable, it's what you want. So you don't need to declare a variable for Exception in the catch block to see exception properties during debugging.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I need, thanks.
Also you could just add `$exception` to the watch window.